# Unicode issue with Rprofile.site

Tags: r, unicode

I appear to have an issue with Unicode and Rprofile.site.

Entering a command like

```
setwd("C:/Documents/example/")
```

into Rprofile works, while

```
setwd("C:/Documents/æ/")
```

does not. For this command, I get the error

```
Error in setwd("C:/Documents/Ã¦/") :    cannot change working directory
```

According to Notepad++, the encoding of Rprofile.site is UTF-8 (without BOM), so I don't see what the issue should be.

The command containing the non-ASCII symbol works if it is pasted directly into the R console. This, combined with the misrepresentation of the non-ASCII symbol in the error message, makes it appear that the content of Rprofile isn't interpreted correctly.

Edit: using R 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Changing the encoding of Rprofile to ANSI made it work, though it would still be interesting to know how it could be made to work with UTF-8 (or other encoding).